# NodeJS error comes "can't find body parser"

Tags: node.js, express

When I try to run the NodeJs code using nodemon command. The error says that can't find body-parser.But I included the body-parser requirement in the app.js . But the same error comes over and over again

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

trainInfo = require('./models/trainInfo');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/traindb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send('Hello world');
});

app.get('/api/trainInfo', function (req, res) {
trainInfo.getTrainInfo(function (err, trainInfo) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(trainInfo);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

Comment: `npm i --save body-parser`?

Comment: Yeah check the path `node_modules/body-parser` and see if the code for the package is there.